# How to separate string based on condition?

Tags: sql, sql-server, string, sql-server-2008, t-sql

```
COMMSTR1-NAC-NAM-P-C FCPANAM1-NAC-NAM-P-C CHAZEL1-NAT-CBM-P-C
```

I want to seperate the above string as `(Required Output)`

```
col1       col2         col3     col4         col5    col6
COMMSTR1 NAC-NAM-P-C    FCPANAM1 NAC-NAM-P-C CHAZEL1 NAT-CBM-P-C
```

I've tried this.

```
SELECT Contact_assg_list_src,
Contact_Assg_List_Src = 
(
case WHEN Contact_Assg_List_Src IS NOT NULL and Contact_Assg_List_Src <> ''
then left(Contact_Assg_List_Src,patindex('%[-]%',Contact_Assg_List_Src)-1)
ELSE Contact_Assg_List_Src
END),
(case WHEN Contact_Assg_List_Src IS NOT NULL and Contact_Assg_List_Src <> ''
then substring(Contact_Assg_List_Src,(Patindex('%[-]%',Contact_Assg_List_Src + ' ')-1),len(Contact_Assg_List_Src))
ELSE Contact_Assg_List_Src
END)
from dbo.FBMSRAW;
```

Which gives me output like

```
col1            col2 
COMMSTR1      NAC-NAM-P-C FCPANAM1-NAC-NAM-P-C CHAZEL1-NAT-CBM-P-C
```

How can I check whether the string has space then separate the string based on that **to
get required output?**

Comment: TSQL is not a great tool for string manipulation. Is there a reason you're trying to do this on the server?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever yeah because my work is data cleaning so i can't use other than this.

Comment: the columns are fixed , I mean maximum how many spaces will be there ? can you assume it to 50?

Comment: @ViswanathanIyeor in your expected result it has 6 cokumns.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it efficiently in SQL server, I'd advise using a CLR function.

But if you have to do it in T-SQL, this function will achieve it (slowly, and in an increasingly inefficient way)

```
    create function SplitString
    (
        @splitchar char(1),
        @string varchar(500),
        @index int
    )
    returns varchar(500)
    as
    begin

    declare @split int, @start int, @loop bit, @i int, @ret varchar(500)
        select @start = 0, @i = 0
        select @split = charindex(@splitchar, @string, 0) 

        if @index>0
            select @loop = 1
        else
            select @loop = 0

        while @loop = 1
        begin

            select @start = @split+1
            select @split = charindex(@splitchar, @string, @start+1)

            if @split = 0
            begin
                select @split = len(@string)+1
            end

            select @i = @i + 1
            if @i = @index
            begin
                select @loop = 0
            end

        end
        if @split>@start
            select @ret = substring(@string, @start, @split-@start)
        else
            select @ret = null

        return @ret
    end

    select dbo.SplitString (' ', 'COMMSTR1-NAC-NAM-P-C FCPANAM1-NAC-NAM-P-C CHAZEL1-NAT-CBM-P-C', [0 based column number])
```

Answer (score 0):

I have wrote the following script to suit your needs, but your self you need to add some more logic, understand the following script

Create a dummy table

```
CREATE TABLE TBL_TEMPSTRINGS(STRCOL VARCHAR(200),COL1 VARCHAR(50),
COL2 VARCHAR(50),COL3 VARCHAR(50))
```

Insert values from your table

```
INSERT INTO TBL_TEMPSTRINGS
SELECT Contact_assg_list_src From dbo.FBMSRAW
```

Create a stored procedure to update your dummy table columns, it takes your table name in a string(why you can replace your dummy table with temp table name if you have used)

```
CREATE PROC SP_SPLITWRODS(@TABLENAME VARCHAR(50),@COLCOUNT INT)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @QRY VARCHAR(500)

    CREATE TABLE #TBL_TEMP(STRCOL VARCHAR(200))
    DECLARE @STRCOL VARCHAR(200)
    DECLARE @CURRINDEX INT
    DECLARE @TEMP INT
    DECLARE @COLINDEX INT 
    DECLARE @ROWID INT
    DECLARE @STRLEN INT
    DECLARE @TEMPVALUE VARCHAR(50)
    DECLARE @LASTWORD BIT 
    --CURSOR FOR YOUR TEMP TABLE
    DECLARE CUR_TEMP CURSOR LOCAL FOR SELECT STRCOL FROM #TBL_TEMP

    --CONSTRUCT QRY FOR FILLING YOUR TABLE
    SET @QRY='INSERT INTO #TBL_TEMP SELECT STRCOL FROM ' + @TABLENAME

    --FILL TABLE
    EXECUTE(@QRY)

    OPEN CUR_TEMP
    FETCH CUR_TEMP INTO @STRCOL
    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN
        SET @CURRINDEX=1
        SET @COLINDEX=1
        SET @LASTWORD=0
        --GET ' ' INDEX
        SET @TEMP=CHARINDEX(' ',@STRCOL,@CURRINDEX)
        WHILE @TEMP > 0
        BEGIN
            --YOU WILL GET THE VALUE SEPERATED BY SPACE
            SET @TEMPVALUE=SUBSTRING(@STRCOL,@CURRINDEX,@TEMP-@CURRINDEX)

            --ADD MORE LOGIC TO UPDATE YOUR COLUMNS (YOUR EXTRA COLUMNS)

            --CONTRUCT QRY TO UPDATE CORRESPONDING COL IN YOUR TABLE FOR THE ROW FETCHED
            --THIS UPDATES ALL ROWS, YOU NEED TO ADD ONE WHERE CONDITION TO UPDATE THE ROW
            SET @QRY='UPDATE ' + @TABLENAME + ' SET COL' + CAST(@COLINDEX AS VARCHAR) + '=''' + @TEMPVALUE + ''''

            EXEC(@QRY)

            --INCREMENT COL INDEX AFTER UPDATE OF LAST COLUMN
            SET @COLINDEX=@COLINDEX+1

            SET @CURRINDEX=@TEMP+1

            SET @TEMP=CHARINDEX(' ',@STRCOL,@CURRINDEX)

            IF @TEMP=0 AND @LASTWORD=0
            BEGIN
                SET @TEMP=LEN(@STRCOL)+1
                SET @LASTWORD=1
            END
        END

        FETCH CUR_TEMP INTO @STRCOL
    END

    CLOSE CUR_TEMP

    DEALLOCATE CUR_TEMP

END
```

Execute your proc

```
EXEC SP_SPLITWRODS 'TBL_TEMPSTRINGS',1
```

See your updated dummy table

```
SELECT * FROM TBL_TEMPSTRINGS
```

Presently it is updates 3 columns split by the space, you need to add your own logic to update the columns based on the string you have received(seperated by space).

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

First a function to split the text

```
create function [dbo].[f_split]
(
@param nvarchar(max), 
@delimiter char(1)
)
returns @t table (val nvarchar(max), seq int)
as
begin
set @param += @delimiter

;with a as
(
select cast(1 as bigint) f, charindex(@delimiter, @param) t, 1 seq
union all
select t + 1, charindex(@delimiter, @param, t + 1), seq + 1
from a
where charindex(@delimiter, @param, t + 1) > 0
)
insert @t
select substring(@param, f, t - f), seq from a
option (maxrecursion 0)
return
end
go
```

Query to display the result, assuming there are max 6 'words'

```
declare @t table(txt nvarchar(500))

insert @t values ('COMMSTR1-NAC-NAM-P-C FCPANAM1-NAC-NAM-P-C CHAZEL1-NAT-CBM-P-C'),
('t1 t2 t3 t4 t5 t6')

select * from @t t
outer apply
(
select max(case when seq = 1 then val end) col1,
       max(case when seq = 2 then val end) col2,
       max(case when seq = 3 then val end) col3,
       max(case when seq = 4 then val end) col4,
       max(case when seq = 5 then val end) col5,
       max(case when seq = 6 then val end) col6
from dbo.f_split(t.txt, ' ')
) b
```

Comment: sorry I deleted my comment your code is working fine but I'm getting error when I'm doing like this. `SELECT Contact_assg_list_src,dbo.f_split(Contact_Assg_List_Src,' ')
from dbo.FBMSRAW`
error is `Cannot find either column "dbo" or the user-defined function or aggregate "dbo.f_split", or the name is ambiguous.`

Comment: I've created function properly and your code works on your given example.